# Tapping Status bar calls tool bar button action method

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a view with toolbar and web view. Toolbar is just below the status bar and it have buttons on it. Now when i disable tool bar  button then on tapping on status bar it scrolls web view to top but when i enable the toolbar buttons then if i tap on status bar then it call home or "<"  button action method. 
**This is happening in iOS 5 not in iOS 4**

**But i want that web view  should scroll to top on tapping the status bar. But it is calling "Home" and "<" button action method**

Now have you any idea how to handle this problem.

[image]

Comment: Yes I have an idea, You need to rephrase your question :)! Sorry buddy can't understand what behaviour you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a bug, but more like intended behavior. The hit area of the `UIBarButtonItem`s are larger than the image of the button. When you tap the status bar near the home button, you're actually tapping inside of the home button's tappable area. In my opinion a toolbar like that belongs at the bottom of the screen anyway within easy reach of the user's thumb.